# Manipulating stack pointer in assembly

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly

I have written an assembly program to store digits in a stack. And to print the digits I have used

```
loop2:
mov ah,2
int 21h
sub cl,1
jnz loop2
```

But this would only print them in reverse order as the SP is pointing to the last element,
Now, I have a very simple yet very interesting question, I was very curious to know
If I were to print it in the same way it was entered, how would I do that? I could use another stack but it would be quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

A stack is a *last-in-first-out* structure. This causes the reverse order you experience. What you need is a *first-in-first-out* structure, i.e., a queue.

This way or another, the stack in x86 is just a region in the memory you can access directly. Instead of **popping** each digit, initialize BP to point at the bottom of your stack (the first digit), then print it, and then advance BP to the next digit (i.e., decrease BP since the stack grows towards lower addresses). At the end of the print loop, just clean the stack by popping everything out, or by changing SP directly.

```
MOV BP, SP    ; init BP to the first digit

... <push digits> , <init CX> ...

PrintLoop:
   MOV DX, [BP]
   MOV AH, 2
   INT 21h            ; print

   SUB BP, 2          ; assuming each digit is a word
   LOOP PrintLoop     ; Loop according to CX

MOV SP, <...>         ; restore stack / "pop" everything
```

Comment: There is a problem I am facing using this, the program is now printing an empty character at the beginning, like instead of just printing "12345", it is printing an empty space at first like " 12345", is it a issue or does it always happen like that?

Comment: Maybe you initialized BP to the wrong place or initialized a wrong counter and thus you are printing an extra space for some reason.

Comment: yeah, i fixed this issue by decreasing the BP by 2 before the print loop, it works fine. Thanks.